# Converting DOCX to Markdown fails to place image

Tags: markdown, mammoth

I am trying to use Mammoth to convert a DOCX file with images to Markdown format:

```
mammoth git.docx --output-format=markdown > git.md
```

When I push the `git.md` to `github` and checked it. It shows no images

When I open `git.md` in text editor the following is used for image

```
![](data:image/png;base64,jasdkjh)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect GitHub doesn't like the inlined image data. Try providing an [`--output-dir`](https://github.com/mwilliamson/python-mammoth#images):

> By default, images are included inline in the output HTML. If an output directory is specified by `--output-dir`, the images are written to separate files instead. For instance:
>
> ```
> mammoth document.docx --output-dir=output-dir
> ```
>
> Existing files will be overwritten if present.

Comment: I will try it and see